# Will Google Analytics have any problems if I use it on User Restricted pages

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, asp.net-mvc-5

Looking at the JavaScript they use, it seems that there should not be any issues. It looks as if it is just pushing some simple data up to google. Just wondering if there is anything I should think about when using Google Analytics on User Restricted ASP.NET MVC pages, or any restricted page for that matter.

I'm also thinking of tracking regular users vs admin users, most of which use separate pages, but I could load one google analytics script over another depending on the user role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use Google Analytics on those pages.

Comment: What about tracking users with different roles separately though? In other words, let's say I wanted to track regular logged in users as well as Admins with a specific role?

Comment: In that case it sounds like you should look into "User Segements" and "Custom Variables" in Google Analytics:  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingCustomVariables

Comment: I should have put that in my question I think I will update it! Thanks!

Comment: Haha... really? I don't get out much that's surprising. lol But I see you're in Central Florida. From a MeetUp or something? I'm just joining StackOverflow now, trying to have more presence in the community.

Comment: Actually, I just went to your website and realized that you were not the same Jason. But I'm sure as developers in Orlando we have probably been in the same circles somewhere, I'm @httpJunkie on twitter. If you want to talk more in the future or ever need help with anything I'm a big community guy. Nice meeting you Jason! Thanks for the insight, I rarely use Google Analytics...